# How do I display rows that have made at least two donations?

Tags: sql, oracle

I can't figure out how to use Count or GROUP By clauses the right way and I can't get rows that make more than 2 donations to display.

I did a failed attempt at a COUNT and GROUP BY Clause.

```
insert into DD (Donor_ID, Donation_ID, Donation_Type, Donation, Inventory_ID) values 
   (1, 1, 'Food', 'Oranges', 1); -- **Code to display**
   insert into DD (Donor_ID, Donation_ID, Donation_Type, Donation, Inventory_ID) values 
   (2, 2, 'Currency', 200, 2); -- **Code to display**
   insert into DD (Donor_ID, Donation_ID, Donation_Type, Donation, Inventory_ID) values 
   (2, 3, 'Currency', 300, 2); -- **Code to display**
   insert into DD (Donor_ID, Donation_ID, Donation_Type, Donation, Inventory_ID) values 
   (1, 4, 'Currency', 400, 2); -- **Code to display**
   insert into DD (Donor_ID, Donation_ID, Donation_Type, Donation, Inventory_ID) values 
   (3, 5, 'Currency', 500, 2); -- NOT TOO display

select di.Donor_Name DI, 
    acz.Address_City ACZ, 
    dd.Donation_Type DD, 
    dd.Donation      DD,
    COUNT(*)

from DI di, ACZ acz, DD dd  
where  di.Donor_ID = acz.Address_ID 
AND (acz.Address_City = 'ATHENS' OR acz.Address_City = 'Watkinsville') 
AND di.Donor_ID > 1
GROUP BY di.Donor_Name DI, 
    acz.Address_City ACZ, 
    dd.Donation_Type DD, 
    dd.Donation      DD;
```

The result I get is an error ORA-00933. The result I want is the commented code mentioned as "-- Code to display" to display.

Comment: You get `error ORA-00933` because you use in the `GROUP BY` clause aliases for the columns. Remove them. But this is only a syntactical error. You have the condition `di.Donor_ID > 1` but you expect `di.Donor_ID = 1` in the results??!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the right way to write the query:

```
select di.Donor_Id, di.Donor_Name,
       count(distinct di.donation_id) as num_donations
from di join
     dd
     on di.Donor_ID = dd.Donor_id join   -- guessing the JOIN conditions
     acz
     on acz.Donor_ID = di.Donor_ID       -- guessing the JOIN conditions
where acz.Address_City in ('ATHENS', 'Watkinsville') and
      di.Donor_ID > 1
group by di.Donor_Id, di.Donor_Name
having count(*) >= 2;
```

Notes:

- **Always use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.** *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- You don't specify the `JOIN` conditions, so I am guessing that `donor_id` is in every table.
- You cannot select the "bare" donation columns if you want to count the number of donations per person.
- A donor could (presumably) have multiple address, so if you want to count donations, use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.
- Oracle is case-sensitive, so it is unusual to see one city name in all caps and the other not.

Comment: Had minor errors, but it fixed it a bit. The code did not display the data fully correct. Only donor 2 displayed when I fixed it.

Comment: Here code that ran correctly: select dd.Donor_Id, di.Donor_Name, 
       count(distinct dd.donation_id) as num_donations 
from di join 
     dd 
     on di.Donor_ID = dd.Donor_id join   -- guessing the JOIN conditions 
     acz 
     on acz.Address_ID = dd.Donor_ID       -- guessing the JOIN conditions 
where acz.Address_City in ('ATHENS', 'Watkinsville') and 
      di.Donor_ID > 1 
group by dd.Donor_Id, di.Donor_Name 
having count(*) >= 2

Answer (score 1):

Your data sample seems to be missing the join between DI and DD.

You should not use the same  name for table and alias (overall SQL code is case insensitive).

You should use explicit join syntax (and not old 1992 implicit join syntax based on `where`) and for at least two donation you could use `having count(*) > 1`.

```
select di.Donor_Name DI, 
    acz.Address_City ACZ, 
    dd.Donation_Type DD, 
    dd.Donation      DD,
    COUNT(*)
from DI 
INNER JOIN ACZ  ON  di.Donor_ID = acz.Address_ID 
        AND (acz.Address_City = 'ATHENS' OR acz.Address_City = 'Watkinsville') 
        AND di.Donor_ID > 1
INNER JOIN  DD  ON DD.Donor_ID =  di.Donor_ID
GROUP BY di.Donor_Name DI, 
    acz.Address_City ACZ, 
    dd.Donation_Type DD, 
    dd.Donation      DD
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Comment: I got the an error running this code. ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `having` clause as it is applied after grouping and works on `aggregate` function result. In you case the condition should be `count(1) > 1`

Use `group by` and `having` as following:

```
select di.Donor_Name DI, 
    acz.Address_City ACZ, 
    dd.Donation_Type DD, 
    dd.Donation      DD,
    COUNT(*)
from DI di, ACZ acz, DD dd  
where  di.Donor_ID = acz.Address_ID 
AND (acz.Address_City = 'ATHENS' OR acz.Address_City = 'Watkinsville') 
AND di.Donor_ID > 1
GROUP BY di.Donor_Name, 
    acz.Address_City, 
    dd.Donation_Type, 
    dd.Donation
Having count(1) > 1; -- use this having
```

Please note that you must use standard ANSI joins.

Cheers!!

Comment: I got an error when I ran this code. ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.

Comment: Please share the query that you executed.

Comment: select di.Donor_Name DI,  
    acz.Address_City ACZ,  
    dd.Donation_Type DD,  
    dd.Donation      DD, 
    COUNT(*) 
from DI di, ACZ acz, DD dd   
where  di.Donor_ID = acz.Address_ID  
AND (acz.Address_City = 'ATHENS' OR acz.Address_City = 'Watkinsville')  
AND di.Donor_ID > 1 
GROUP BY di.Donor_Name,  
    acz.Address_City,  
    dd.Donation_Type,  
    dd.Donation 
Having Count(1) > 1; -- use this having